# Visual Studio 2015 .jar reference

Tags: java, plugins, visual-studio-2015

Does anyone know how I can refer to a .jar file in the Visual Studio 2015 project with plugin "Java Language Service for Android and Eclipse Android Project Import" (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/53e6e65b-fa0f-411a-a98d-7911009537ac)?

Comment: Did you find a solution to reference a *.jar file?

Comment: Nothing unfortunately

Comment: I'm facing this problem now with Visual Studio 2017. I found something similar but it didn't work with a `libs` folder either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401460/add-jar-to-visual-studio-2015-android-ant-java-project

Answer (score 0):

In the "project.properties" file of Android project there is a line

```
# Provide path to the directory where prebuilt external jar files are by setting jar.libs.dir=
```

There should be a way to add a folder with jars but i didn't manage to find out it.