# Add JAR to Visual Studio 2015 Android Ant Java project

Tags: java, android, ant, visual-studio-2015

I used the Visual C++/Cross Platform/Android/Basic Application (Android, Ant) template to create a project in Visual Studio 2015.

I want to add a .jar file to the project and for the life of me cannot find any documentation on how to do this. I copied the .jar to the android /libs folder, but it is not finding it on build.

Comment: Why are you using not the standard build system (Gradle) and not the recommended free IDE (Android Studio)?

Comment: Because Android Studio doesn't support NDK and the alpha/beta versions of gradle that supposedly do are a total bitch with the instructions changing each version. :)

Comment: Have you tried adding `jar.libs.dir=libs` in the `project.properties` file in order to make the libraries available for compile?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue when attempting to add fmod to an android project in Visual Studio 2015.

What ended up working for me was creating a "libs" folder in the same directory as my "src" and "res" folders, placing the .jar in there, and including that in my Android project (marking it as "Content" in the Property Pages in Visual Studio).